# Visual Studio Unit Test

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2013

I'm currently learning unit test (visual studio integrated)

Been following this [Create and run unit tests within visual studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/code/create-and-run-unit-tests-vs)

I have the following unit test

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void GetMovieTitle()
    {
        var mc = new MoviesController();

        var rep = mc.GetById(22);

        Assert.AreEqual("Horrible Bosses", rep.Title);

    }
```

When I test, it passes.  But I want to output the following :

The movie with an id of 22 has the title “Horrible Bosses”

And I'm not sure how I go about doing it? I have tried looking on the web before coming here but due to my lack of experience with unit tests I'm uncertain on what to google for.

** Update **

When I refer to "out put" I mean inside the following, can you display the response as well as just saying the below?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean with output? where do you want this message to appear?

Comment: How do you want it to be output? Output to where?

Comment: @PrimeByDesign I would like to see the message appear under the success or fail within the photo I've just attached to the question

Comment: Change your GetMovieTitle method to the description you want... e.g.MovieTitleIsCorrect()

Comment: @PrimeByDesign sorry i'm not sure what you mean

Comment: As far as I am aware wheb you test you usually just give your test method a better name. Yours is GetMovieTitle()... Change it to something else and that is what you'll see in the text output. That is how you do it.

Answer (score 1):

Change the name of your test to

```
public void The_movie_with_an_id_of_22_has_the_title_Horrible_Bosses()
{
}
```